# Write a program that reads your first name and displays your name with stars separating each letter

Tags: java

I was having problem with the output: it always puts an extra star at the end when there isn't suppose to be. Sample:

```
m*i*c*h*a*e*l*
```

When it is suppose to not have an asterisk after `l` or the last character. Can anyone help me figure this out? Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CoolSet2Problem3
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter your first name in all     lowercase: ");
        String name = keyboard.next();
        int n = 0;
        String star = "*";

        while (n < name.length())
        {
            System.out.print(name.charAt(n) + star);
            n++;
        }
    }
}
```

My teacher told me that we might have to do something with ASCII character sets, which I have no idea about.

Comment: Do you see why this happens? Do you have any ideas on how to stop the last `*` from appearing? You can figure this out!

Comment: You want to add a special case for that last star, so that you only concatenate/append it if your current character **IS NOT** the last character or you can remove the last star when you are finished adding all the stars.

Comment: In your loop you add a '*' into each and every character. The thing is you should not to it with the last character. So you need to modify your loop accordingly

Comment: He might have thought of the DEL-character with ASCII code 127. However, this symbol does not really work, unless you are using punch cards...

Answer (score 0):

Well when you print the last character you are adding a star at the end of it... Thats why there is one being added at the end.

Try this:

```
    while (n < name.length() - 1)
        {
            System.out.print(name.charAt(n) + star);
            n++;
        }
    System.out.print(name.charAt(n));
```

Comment: Thank you. I am a little lost because I went into this class 2 weeks late.

Comment: Suggestion: I went down the same path as you when I went into college(was a little late to a few classes). If you do not take the time to catch up now, You are really really going to fall behind. Seriously take a weekend even a whole week, sit down and force yourself to go through all the material and code all the examples. Don't do this for the grade, this material will get you the best jobs in the world, best pay, best work life, most flexibility, best everything. Trust me on this, you do not want to fall behind on the basics.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of approaches.  One simple one is to check a boundary condition to see if the star should be printed, e.g.

```
while (n < name.length())
{
    if (n != 0) System.out.print(star);
    System.out.print(name.charAt(n));
    n++;
}
```